# row = i+1 in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

What am I doing wrong? Each grid row should be i + 1, so they would go one under another, right?

What's happening is that only the last of the loop is visible in tkinter, on the first row, so I think the other ones are been grided under this one, so I'm not able to see It or place it below.

```
   for l in resposta_file:
        i = 0
        if 'VERMELHO' in l:
            update = 'VERMELHO'
        if 'AMARELO' in l:
            update = 'AMARELO'
        if 'VERDE' in l:
            update = 'VERDE'
        if 'NOME:' in l:
            nome = re.search(r'NOME:(.*)', l).group(1)
            nome_plc = Label(frame_nome, text=nome)
            nome_plc.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=EW)

        elif 'IDADE:' in l:
            split = l.split(' // ')
            age = re.search('IDADE:(.*)', split[0]).group(1)
            idade = int(age)
            cidade = re.search('CIDADE:(.*)', split[1]).group(1)
            beneficio = re.search('BENEFÍCIO:(.*)', split[2]).group(1)
            salario = re.search('SALÁRIO:(.*)', split[3]).group(1)
            bancos = re.search('BANCOS:(.*)', split[4]).group(1)
            quantidade = re.search('QNT:(.*)', split[5]).group(1)
            qnt = int(quantidade)
            card = re.search('CARTÃO:(.*)', split[6]).group(1)
            mg_consig = re.search('MG. CONSIG:(.*)', split[7]).group(1)
            mg_card = re.search('MG. CARD:(.*)', split[8]).group(1)

            if idade < 75:
                idade_plc = Label(frame_idade, text=idade, borderwidth=1, relief="groove")
                idade_plc.grid(row=i + 1, column=0, sticky=EW)
            elif idade > 75:
                idade_plc = Label(frame_idade, text=idade, borderwidth=1, relief="groove", bg='red')
                idade_plc.grid(row=i + 1, column=0, sticky=EW)
            benef_plc = Label(frame_nbenef, text=beneficio, borderwidth=1, relief="groove")
            benef_plc.grid(row=i + 1, column=0, sticky=EW)
            agencia_plc = Label(frame_cidade, text=cidade, borderwidth=1, relief="groove")
            agencia_plc.grid(row=i + 1, column=0, sticky=EW)
            wckToolTips.register(agencia_plc, cidade)
            salario_plc = Label(frame_salario, text=salario, borderwidth=1, relief="groove")
            salario_plc.grid(row=i + 1, column=0, sticky=EW)
            wckToolTips.register(salario_plc, salario)
            bancos_plc = Label(frame_bancos, text=bancos, borderwidth=1, relief="groove")
            bancos_plc.grid(row=i + 1, column=0, sticky=EW)
            wckToolTips.register(bancos_plc, bancos)
            if qnt >= 9:
                qnt_plc = Label(frame_qnt, text=qnt, borderwidth=1, relief="groove", bg='red')
                qnt_plc.grid(row=i + 1, column=0, sticky=EW)
            elif qnt < 9:
                qnt_plc = Label(frame_qnt, text=qnt, borderwidth=1, relief="groove")
                qnt_plc.grid(row=i + 1, column=0, sticky=EW)
            card_plc = Label(frame_card, text=card, borderwidth=1, relief="groove")
            card_plc.grid(row=i + 1, column=0, sticky=EW)
            wckToolTips.register(card_plc, card)
            mgconsig_plc = Label(frame_mgconsig, text=mg_consig, borderwidth=1, relief="groove")
            mgconsig_plc.grid(row=i + 1, column=0, sticky=EW)
            mgcard_plc = Label(frame_mgcard, text=mg_card, borderwidth=1, relief="groove")
            mgcard_plc.grid(row=i + 1, column=0, sticky=EW)
            i += 1
```

Comment: Put i=0 outside of the loop and unindent the last i+=1

Comment: More pythonic way is to change `for l in resposta_files:` to `for i, l in enumerate(resposta_file):`, then remove the `i = 0` and `i += 1` lines.